# HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr() implementation on Weblogic 9.2.3 using JAX-RPC

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, jax-rpc, weblogic9.x

Salut,

I am new in Weblogic WebService implementation. Trying to get client's remote address from SOAP message using JAX-RPC. Need to get client's remote IP from SOAP message header. Tried many solutions according BEA/Oracle documentation.
WebService java file:

```
@WebService
public class clientsIPWs {
    @Control
    private SoapMessageControl smc;

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name="return")
    public String getClientAddress() {
        return smc.getRemoteAddress();
    }

}
```

SoapMessageControl.java

```
@ControlInterface
public interface SoapMessageControl {

    public String getRemoteAddress();

}
```

SoapMessageControlImpl.java

```
@ControlImplementation
public class SoapMessageControlImpl implements SoapMessageControl, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Context
    private SOAPMessageContext smc;

    @WebMethod()
    public String getRemoteAddress() {
        HttpServletRequest request = 
            (HttpServletRequest) smc.getProperty("transport.http.servletRequest");
        return request.getRemoteAddr();
    }
}
```

In the last one tried many variations with @Context like MessageContext / WebServiceContext (this one is deprecated), but everytime in testing received such exception:

> Failed to invoke end component Failed to invoke method
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at controls.SoapMessageControlImpl.getRemoteAddress(SoapMessageControlImpl.java:33)
>           at controls.SoapMessageControlBean.getRemoteAddress(SoapMessageControlBean.java:119)
>           at services.CustProdWs.getClientAddress(CustProdWs.java:63)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
>           at weblogic.wsee.component.pojo.JavaClassComponent.invoke(JavaClassComponent.java:99)
>           at weblogic.wsee.ws.dispatch.server.ComponentHandler.handleRequest(ComponentHandler.java:64)
>           at weblogic.wsee.handler.HandlerIterator.handleRequest(HandlerIterator.java:127)
>           at weblogic.wsee.ws.dispatch.server.ServerDispatcher.dispatch(ServerDispatcher.java:85)
>           at weblogic.wsee.ws.WsSkel.invoke(WsSkel.java:80)
>           at weblogic.wsee.server.servlet.SoapProcessor.handlePost(SoapProcessor.java:66)
>           at weblogic.wsee.server.servlet.SoapProcessor.process(SoapProcessor.java:44)
>           at weblogic.wsee.server.servlet.BaseWSServlet$AuthorizedInvoke.run(BaseWSServlet.java:181)
>           at weblogic.wsee.server.servlet.BaseWSServlet.service(BaseWSServlet.java:92)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3244)
>           at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>           at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2010)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:1916)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1366)
>           at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
>           at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181)

In google almost every solution uses JAX-WS that is not available for me in this framework.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

> Getting the HttpServletRequest/Response Object
>
> If your Web Service uses HTTP as its transport protocol, you can use
>   the weblogic.wsee.connection.transport.servlet.HttpTransportUtils API
>   to get the javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest and
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse objects from the JAX-RPC
>   ServletEndpointContext object, as shown in the following example
>   (relevant code shown in bold and explained after the example):

```
 package examples.webservices.http_transport_utils;
 import javax.xml.rpc.server.ServiceLifecycle;
import javax.xml.rpc.server.ServletEndpointContext;
import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
 import weblogic.jws.WLHttpTransport;
 import weblogic.wsee.connection.transport.servlet.HttpTransportUtils;
 @WebService(name="HttpTransportUtilsPortType",
            serviceName="HttpTransportUtilsService",
            targetNamespace="http://example.org")
 @WLHttpTransport(contextPath="servlet", serviceUri="HttpTransportUtils",
                 portName="HttpTransportUtilsPort")
 public class HttpTransportUtilsImpl implements ServiceLifecycle {
   private ServletEndpointContext wsctx = null;
   public void init(Object context) throws ServiceException {
    System.out.println("ServletEndpointContext inited...");
    wsctx = (ServletEndpointContext)context;
  }
   public void destroy() {
    System.out.println("ServletEndpointContext destroyed...");
    wsctx = null;
  }
   @WebMethod()
  public String getServletRequestAndResponse() {
     HttpServletRequest request =
       HttpTransportUtils.getHttpServletRequest(wsctx.getMessageContext());
    HttpServletResponse response =
       HttpTransportUtils.getHttpServletResponse(wsctx.getMessageContext());
     System.out.println("HttpTransportUtils API used successfully.");
    return "HttpTransportUtils API used successfully";
   }
 }
```